# Use a button to show and close the matplotlib real-time graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm building a program where I have a real-time graph using using matplotlib. I'm using tkinter to make 2 buttons: "graph it" which opens a new window to graph the plot and "clear" to close the window. The problem is that when I close the window for the first time with the "clear" button, I cannot re-show the graph with the "graph it" button. Instead it gives me this error:

```
"UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely 
not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.
```

here is the code that I have:

```
import datetime as dt
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from tkinter import *
#import tmp102

# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys2 = []
ys = []

# Initialize communication with TMP102
#tmp102.init()

# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i,xs, ys, ys2):

    # Read temperature (Celsius) from TMP102
    #temp_c = round(tmp102.read_temp(), 2)

    num_random = random.randint(0,100)
    num_random2 = random.randint(0,100)
    # Add x and y to lists
    xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
    ys.append(num_random)
    ys2.append(num_random2)

    # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
    xs = xs[-15:]
    ys = ys[-15:]
    ys2 = ys2[-15:]

    # Draw x and y lists
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys, ys2)

    # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.title('TMP102 Temperature over Time')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (deg C)')

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
def graph():
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys, ys2), interval=1000)
    plt.show()

def clear():
    plt.close()

root = Tk()
root.title('matplot with tkinter test')
root.geometry("400x200")

my_button = Button(root, text="Graph it", command=graph)
my_button.pack()

clear_button = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear)
clear_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want the button to be able to show and close the real-time graph anytime the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

When you run `plt.close()`, you are essentially deleting the figure `fig` you've created earlier so you have to recreate the figure.

```
# Create figure for plotting
def create_figure():  # <-- turned into a method
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xs = []
    ys2 = []
    ys = []
    return fig, ax, xs, ys2, ys

def animate(i,xs, ys, ys2, ax):  # <-- added ax as an argument
    # body omitted

def graph():
    fig, ax, xs, ys2, ys = create_figure()  # <-- recreate the figure object
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys, ys2, ax), interval=1000)
    plt.show()

def clear():
    plt.close()

root = Tk()
...
```

Alternatively you could look for some other command than `plt.close()` so you don't remove your figure. You could clear it using `plt.clf()` rather than removing the window as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code work perfectly. really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Sure thing! If it answered your question, consider upvoting + marking the answer as correct.